# How to extract data from a concatenated string in excel macro

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Am new to this - trying to pull out a name and date from a concatenated text string - each line has a name with the month - all different and the month must be changed for each search.
[Attached is screenshot of my results using MID that extracts date][1]

I have attempted MID and RIGHT using first uppercase to the left of the comma but have had no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.

I do have a script that process the data - the following is the VBA code for pulling name and date:
Name 
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(MID(C3,1,FIND(""January"",C3,1)-1),IFERROR(MID(C3,1,FIND(""February"",C3,1)-1),IFERROR(MID(C3,1,FIND(""March"",C3,1)-1),IFERROR(MID(C3,1,FIND(""April"",C3,1)-1),IFERROR(MID(C3,1,FIND(""May"",C3,1)-1),IFERROR(MID(C3,1,FIND(""June"",C3,1)-1),IFERROR(MID(C3,1,FIND(""July"",C3,1)-1),IFERROR(MID(C3,1,FIND(""August"",C3,1)-1),IFERROR(MID(C3,1,FIND(""September"",C3,1)-1),IFERROR(MID(C3,1,FIND(""October"",C3,1)-1),IFERROR(MID(C3,1,FIND(""November"",C3,1)-1),IFERROR(MID(C3,1,FIND(""December"",C3,1)-1),""No matches""))))))))))))"

Date
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(MID(C3,FIND(""January"",C3)*1,20),IFERROR(MID(C3,FIND(""February"",C3)*1,20),IFERROR(MID(C3,FIND(""March"",C3)*1,20),IFERROR(MID(C3,FIND(""April"",C3)*1,20),IFERROR(MID(C3,FIND(""May"",C3)*1,20),IFERROR(MID(C3,FIND(""June"",C3)*1,20),IFERROR(MID(C3,FIND(""July"",C3)*1,20),IFERROR(MID(C3,FIND(""August"",C3)*1,20),IFERROR(MID(C3,FIND(""September"",C3)*1,20),IFERROR(MID(C3,FIND(""October"",C3)*1,20),IFERROR(MID(C3,FIND(""November"",C3)*1,20),IFERROR(MID(C3,FIND(""December"",C3)*1,20),""nope""))))))))))))"

I'm sure there is an easier way - I just haven't figured it out and I'm being pressured to get this data out -

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT92Q.jpg

Comment: Very easy with VBA..............is this option acceptable to you??

Comment: Yes - I run VBA script now using the same methodology with, unfortunately, the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two User Defined Functions:

```
Public Function DateGrabber(s As String) As Date
    Dim temp As String, temp2 As String, i As Long, L As Long
    temp = s
    temp2 = ""
    L = Len(s)
    For i = L To 1 Step -1
        temp2 = Mid(temp, i, 1) & temp2

        If Mid(temp, i, 1) Like "[A-Z]" Then
            DateGrabber = CDate(temp2)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function


Public Function DateDiscarder(s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, L As Long
    L = Len(s)
    For i = L To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(s, i, 1) Like "[A-Z]" Then
            DateDiscarder = Left(s, i - 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

This first function walks backwards from the end of the string until it finds the **first capital letter**. That is how it finds the date part.

The second UDF just discards the date using the same criteria:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome - filled a life goal of learning something new every day - Many thanks -

Comment: @Shellback  just like me...that's why my username is Student